# How to reuse a domain already in use in vercel?

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm already running a Next.js-based blog at thisishaneum.com. However, I want to create a separate portfolio page apart from the blog. So, I attempted to create a new page by making a 'portfolio' directory in the blog repository.

However, there are too many configurations already set up, and I want to use the domain thisishaneum.com/portfolio but with a new repository instead of the thisishaneum.com repository.

Is there a way to achieve this? Should I just create the project in the original blog repository and serve it? Or is there a way to configure the domain thisishaneum.com/portfolio to be used only by the new repository?

Comment: You could create a subdomain with a new project, for example: blog.thisishaneum.com.

Comment: Umm i could know what you say. but how I create a subdomain in Vercel? Plz let me know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

thisishaneum.com and thisishaneum.com/portfolio are the same domain, the /portfolio is a path.

A domain can only be pointed at one project in vercel. So if you want to use thisishaneum.com/portfolio it will either need to be in the same project, or you will need to proxy request from one project to the other.

You'll want to deploy your things to their own projects. Once you have those deployed, on the vercel domain, you can then proxy requests to it using rewrites from the vercel.json file.

They have a guide [here](https://vercel.com/docs/projects/project-configuration#rewrites)

And you probably want to set this up as a mono repo, although I don't think that is absolutely necessary per se it just might get a bit easier in terms of deploying.

Comment: My english so bad, I am so sorry. "However, there are too many configurations already set up, and I want to use the domain thisishaneum.com/portfolio" means that my portfolio project, thisishaneum.com, has configurations (global css, markdown css, ...) so I can't create new project in my portfolio project. so I want to make new project but I want to use the domain thisishaneum.com/portfolio.

Comment: how to deploy Like https://david-peter.de/ project? https://david-peter.de/ is https://github.com/sharkdp/dp project, but https://david-peter.de/cube-composer/ is https://github.com/sharkdp/cub-composer project. But those two project has each github repository. How configurate this?

Comment: Ah gotcha, you'll probably want to setup a mono repo. And then to make the different projects available on the same domain you'll ned to proxy requests from one to the other.

You can setup proxy requets in vercel.json with rewrites: https://vercel.com/docs/projects/project-configuration#rewrites